# ASP.NET MVC Adding Cookies doesn't work if Domain Set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcookie

I am trying to add two cookies to application. One I need the domain to ".site.com", but that one does not show in the Cookies.

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, emailAddress, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12), true, accessToken);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12)
            };

        var subDomainCookie = new HttpCookie("site.session.token", accessToken)
        {
            HttpOnly = false,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(12),
            Domain = ".site.com",
            Path = "/",
            Shareable = true
        };            

        
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Cookies.Add(subDomainCookie);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Also If I set Domain = "localhost", the cookie shows up fine. But I need this cookie to accessible by subdomains.

Comment: Found the cookie doesn't show in localhost environment, but when I deploy to qa environment it shows up as long my domain has .site.com